# Clicking on List Item also clicks the checkboxes inside item

Tags: android

I've a  listview where each listitem has a checkbox. When I click list item, OnItemClick is called but checkbox is also clicked, that's annoying coz checbox onclick actions are triggered.

Edit:
how can I prevent checkbox from being clicked when row Item is clicked?

Comment: Can you restate this in the form of a question?

Comment: Hi. I updated my answer. It was not correct. Hope, it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:**
Try to add to root view of the listitem layout this attribute `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`.

This should work